# bootstrap4 columns and rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a code with a row that has two columns and three rows. In the mobile device it does not appear well with some cols appearing longer than others.
Below is the code.

Below is the code that I currently have

```
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
        <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6; cursor: pointer;">
            <a ><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="{{=URL('static', 'images/burn.jpg')}}" style="height:auto;"/></a>
            <a ><p class="audiowide" style="">Track more</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
        <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
            <a ><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="{{=URL('static', 'images/burn.jpg')}}"style="height:auto;" /></a>
            <a ><p class="audiowide" style="">Track more</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
        <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
            <a ><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="{{=URL('static', 'images/policy.jpg')}}" style="height:auto;"/></a>
            <a ><p class="audiowide" style="">Track more</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
        <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
            <a ><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="{{=URL('static', 'images/burn.jpg')}}" style="height:auto;"/></a>
            <a><p class="audiowide" style="">Track more</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
        <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
            <a ><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="{{=URL('static', 'images/burn.jpg')}}" style="height:auto;"/></a>
            <a ><p class="audiowide" style="">Track more</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
        <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
            <a ><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="{{=URL('static', 'images/burn.jpg')}}" style="height:auto;"/></a>
            <a><p class="audiowide" style="">Track more</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to have all the cols appearing the same width and height. Two cols and three rows in the mobile device. The current three cols and two rows on the desktop is OK for me.

Comment: There is no longer `col-xs-6` .. it's just `col-6`

Comment: just noted that this was in version 3.4

Comment: Then please tag the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this in Bootstrap-3 with grid system & images of variable heights wouldn't be a neat OOTB pure css solution...

1. It is possible with JavaScript getting the Height of one image and
   setting the height of the corresponding shorter card
2. It is possible if you assign a hard number as a height to each card
3. Look at a bootstrap-4 flexbox based solution

Following code (as per number 2 above) uses hard numbers as max-height to give the effect that can help you... the other 2 solutions would require more re-work for you

```css
.likes_comments1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.likes_comments1 a img {
  max-height: 210px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .likes_comments1 a img {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
  <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6; cursor: pointer;">
    <a><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg" style="height:auto;" /></a>
    <a>
      <p class="audiowide" style="">Track more 1</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
  <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
    <a><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" style="height:auto;" /></a>
    <a>
      <p class="audiowide" style="">Track more 2</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
  <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
    <a><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg" style="height:auto;" /></a>
    <a>
      <p class="audiowide" style="">Track more 3</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
  <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
    <a><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" style="height:auto;" /></a>
    <a>
      <p class="audiowide" style="">Track more 4</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
  <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
    <a><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg" style="height:auto;" /></a>
    <a>
      <p class="audiowide" style="">Track more 5</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Audiowide'; font-size: 1.2em;">
  <div class="likes_comments1" style="border-radius:7px; border: solid thin #38D9D6;">
    <a><img class="image img-rounded img-responsive center-block" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" style="height:auto;" /></a>
    <a>
      <p class="audiowide" style="">Track more 6</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```